# NodeJs MongoDB -Having TypeError while updating every document on one field in a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://blablabla:abcdefgh@ds123321.mlab.com:21212/aslanservices", function(err, db) {
  if(err) { return console.dir(err); }
  db.collection('sakins').insert({adsoyad : 'amg amg amg', apartman : 'ferhatapt', daireno : '3', borc : '100' });
  
db.collection('sakins').insert({adsoyad : 'cla cal cla', apartman : 'aslanapt', daireno : '4', borc : '75' });
  
db.collection('sakins').insert({adsoyad : 'bla bla bla', apartman : 'ferhatapt', daireno : '5', borc : '150' });
  
  db.collection('sakins').uptade({'borc' : 'borc' + 75          },function(err,result){
  console.log(result);
});
  db.close();
});//End of Mongoclient connection
```

I can succesfully performing operations such as inserting,finding documents but i cannot uptade and i am having the error below :
         throw error
    Type Error : db.collection(...).uptade is not a function

Can you help me about uptading particular field in every document in the collection named 'sakins' ?

Comment: I also tried to uptade with the code below : 

db.collection('sakins').uptade({}, {$set :{'borc' : 'borc' + 75 }});

Same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misspelled update. Its update not uptade.

Comment: Ahh sorry... had a busy day. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, sometimes errors like this can be the hardest to find

Comment: Also, do you know how to increment it with a particular value like code below  : 

 db.collection('sakins').update({}, {$set :{'borc' : 'borc' + 75 }});

increasing 'borc' like borc += 75; ? how can i do that ?

Comment: Are you trying to update every document in the sarkins collection?

Comment: db.collection('sakins').update({}, {$inc: { borc: 75}});

Comment: Also check out this page https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

Comment: Thank you, so much sir !